# What means dbconfig-common?

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation, debian

I have a simple question.

During installation of PHPMyAdmin it ask you if you want to configure the database with dbconfig-common (Debian).

Can someone please explain to me what dbconfig-common exactly does? What is the difference?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dbconfig-common is a tool which simplifies database configuration. Instead of editing the config-files directly, it provides an UI where you can set up your setting to avoid misconfiguration. You can find more information here: http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt-debian/content/debconf-dbconfig-common.html

Answer (score 0):

dbconfig-common is a simple way to generating database configuration

From documentation: 
"dbconfig-common is an implementation of the "best practices for database applications" draft, which provides debian packagers with an easy, reliable, and consistent method for managing databases used by debian packages."

In case of installation phpmyadmin - you will need to setup your MySQL password and set the password you’ll use to log into phpmyadmin

More information about dbconfig-common here: https://people.debian.org/~seanius/policy/dbconfig-common.html/